# Explode function is increasing job time in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataframe with one column arrs having an array of size close to 100000.
Now I need to explode this column to get unique rows for all the elements of Array.

Explode function of spark.sql is doing the job but is taking enough time 
Any alternative of explode which I can try to optimize job.

```
 dfs.printSchema()
 println("Orginal DF")
 dfs.show()

 //Performing Explode operation
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode,col}
 val opdfs=dfs.withColumn("explarrs",explode(col("arrs"))).drop("arrs")
 println("Exploded DF")
 opdfs.show()
```

Expected result should be as below but an alternative to this code which will optimize the job more efficiently.

Orginal DF

```
+----+------+----+--------------------+
|col1|  col2|col3|                arrs|
+----+------+----+--------------------+
|   A|DFtest|   K|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...|
+----+------+----+--------------------+

Exploded DF
+----+------+----+--------+
|col1|  col2|col3|explarrs|
+----+------+----+--------+
|   A|DFtest|   K|       1|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       2|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       3|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       4|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       5|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       6|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       7|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       8|
|   A|DFtest|   K|       9|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      10|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      11|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      12|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      13|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      14|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      15|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      16|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      17|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      18|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      19|
|   A|DFtest|   K|      20|
+----+------+----+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?. This was fixed in 2.3

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same without explode using **flatMap** method from Dataframe. For example, if you need to explode an array of integers you can proceed with something like:

```
val els = Seq(Row(Array(1, 2, 3)))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(els), StructType(Seq(StructField("data", ArrayType(IntegerType), false))))
df.show()
```

It gives:

```
+---------+
|     data|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+
```

Using Dataframe´s flatmap:

```
df.flatMap(row => row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]](0)).show()

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

The problem with this is that you need to put the right type of the elements of your array in the **getAs** function, in addition to the memory overhead. As I said in my comment there was a bug that was fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657

But if you can´t upgrade your Spark version you can try the code above and compare.

If you want to add the other fields to your result you could do something like:

```
val els = Seq(Row(Array(1, 2, 3), "data1", "data2"), Row(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), "data10", "data20"))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(els),
  StructType(Seq(StructField("data", ArrayType(IntegerType), false), StructField("data1", StringType, false), StructField("data2", StringType, false))))

df.show()

df.flatMap{ row =>
  val arr = row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]](0)
  arr.map { el =>
    (row.getAs[String](1), row.getAs[String](2), el)
  }
}.show()
```

It gives:

```
+------+------+---+
|    _1|    _2| _3|
+------+------+---+
| data1| data2|  1|
| data1| data2|  2|
| data1| data2|  3|
|data10|data20|  1|
|data10|data20|  2|
|data10|data20|  3|
|data10|data20|  4|
|data10|data20|  5|
|data10|data20|  6|
+------+------+---+
```

maybe it can help.

Comment: What if I have multiple columns in my dataframe as below

+----+------+----+------------+
|col1|  col2|col3|        arrs|
+----+------+----+------------+
|   A|DFtest|   K|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
+----+------+----+------------+

Comment: edit your question and add taht content for a better understanding.

Comment: Hi EmiCareOfCell44 --Thanks for the reponse I have edited the question and formatted the content for better understanding

Comment: Above solution for 3 columns is doing my job..But is taking more time as compared to explode method

Comment: It depends on how many many records you have. As explode version has exponential time complexity for  previous versions to 2.3, if your records number increases you can experiment with flatMap version that, a priori, has linear increment.